# Can only create site (from custom defintion) when in central admin

Tags: development, publishing-site, site-definition, site-creation

As title says. I've created the bare basics of a custom site definition (no features etc.).

It, at least appears, to deploy and activate fine judging by VS 2010 output.

If in central admin, I can see this available custom site definition (and many more) in the site actions > new site dialog if I open this dialog from central admin - but not if I'm actually on my site (publishing site).

Why have I lost visibility of many of the site templates both OOTB and my custom site definition?

Also - this doesn't matter so much if it's only a case of the site definition not being visible - because I ultimately want to create a site from this site definition programmatically so as long as I can still do this it's not a problem.

Comment: Which template do you use for your root site?

Comment: Publishing site. Thanks for your reply Hugh, desperate to get to the bottom of this. I've got a suspicion that I'm mis-understanding the fundamentals of SharePoint site templates and features here but I am rather new to it.

Comment: If it is a publishing portal then it is bugged, I can't remember where I read about this before brb I will google I think it is just a powershell script away from a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find it but I found this that I will quote for you because the page is a mess:

> I found the answer. To make additional site  Definitions or Site
>   Templates available in a site based on the Publishing Portal you need
>   to go to Site Actions > Site Settings > Modify All Site Settings. On
>   the Site Settings page click the Page Layouts and Site Templates link
>   under the Look and Feel column. In the Site Templates section of the
>   page that appears you will see a list box to the left that contains
>   all the Site Definitions and Site Templates available in the
>   installation. In the list box on the right you will see a list box
>   containing just Publishing Site with Workflow, which is the only site
>   definition currently available. Find your new site definition  in the
>   box on the left, highlight it and press the Add> button to move it to
>   the box on the right. Click OK and the next time you create  a sub
>   site your new site definition should be available.
>   [[source]](http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/site-definition-examples-dont-appear-7641.aspx)

It was a powershell script that did something under the site to the site definitions and it listed it as a bug that happened when you activated something, but I don't remember how or what, hopefully just trying to reactivate them will help.

Comment: Hugh, I hope you realise how much that's helped me. Thanks so much mate, you've really saved me a lot of messing around there. Spot on.